# Vue3 mounted() is being called several times

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, vite

I have a vue template with a table rendering all items of an array, looking pretty much likes this:

```
<template>
    <thead>
        my table heads...
    </thead>
    <tr v-for="item in items"
        my items
    </tr> 
</template>
```

I have a function that allows me to filter on my DB and replace the value of the items array. My script tag looks like this:

```
<script>
    data(){
        return: {
            items: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async getList(){
            here i do my query...
                .then(this.items = response.data)
        },

        async filter(){
           here i do my query with my filterObj...
                .then(this.items = response.data)
        },
    async mounted(){
        this.getList()
    }
```

This works well. I get to filter and vue's reactiviy auto-reloads my table with the new data. The problem is that I noticed that sometimes, the filter "cancels itself" and the "getList" function is called. I added a console.log() on that function and I noticed that is called 7-8 times when the page is first loaded and it gets called sometimes randomly after my filter is applied. Any ideas?

I read this: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/9231
I do use vite to compile. Could this be my issue? Can anyone reproduce this on a project?

I noticed that the funcionts in my mounted() property are being called several times

Comment: It's a bit difficult to identify the issue given only one component. Since you mentioned that the `mounted` hook is being called several times then the issue can be on its parent. Can you provide more context on this?

Comment: "Can anyone reproduce this on a project" - it's asker's responsibility to provide a way to reproduce, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown under which conditions this happens. Could be random FS changes caused by IDE or else that trigger hot reload. Try to reproduce on fresh project with no IDE running, then it could be shared

Comment: Sure. My bad on that. I will reproduce this myself and update here before asking for more information. Yet, if someone has encountered a similar error using Vue and Vite it would be helpfull to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone, I found out what was happening I want to let this as it may help some rookie like me in the future

I have a component being called on each table row so you could click them and open that dialog. Thing is, I had on that component a $emit being called on the mounted() object for some reason. Maybe I did it when I was testing and forgot to erase it back. This $emit was configured to trigger the function I have on my mounted() object on the parent component, so it looked like it was being called several times. Very dumb

Thanks for the help everyone